# Saving linux boot messages in a file

Tags: linux, logs, startup, raspberry-pi

I have raspbian running on my raspberry PI. When I switch it on, boot messages crawl on the screen. I believe it would be beneficial to read them in order to get an idea about how the system starts. Hence I would like to know whether it is possible (and how) to redirect them to a file in order to read them thoroughly afterwards. Do I have to make a script that runs at startup?

Answer (score 4):

Install the `bootlogd` package. Bootlogd is a daemon that will record all boot messages to `/var/log/boot`. Install the package with:

```
sudo apt-get install bootlogd
```

Then enable it by creating a new file called `bootlogd` in `/etc/default/`:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/bootlogd
```

And add the follwing to the file:

```
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=yes
```

Save and exit. Now all boot messages will be put in `/var/log/boot` file, you can view them by using `less` like this:

```
less /var/log/boot
```

Answer (score 3):

> I have raspbian […]

Then you can use the old Debian [`/etc/init.d/bootlogs`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysvinit/blob/master/debian/src/initscripts/etc/init.d/bootlogs) that saves the last up to 0.5MiB of kernel messages to `/var/log/dmesg` at startup.  And of course, as mentioned in another answer, the old `bootlogd` from the same source, which only captures kernel messages that are at or above the kernel's console minimum log priority level.

And you can use one of the several Debian [kernel log daemons](https://packages.debian.org/sid/linux-kernel-log-daemon) or [system log daemons](https://packages.debian.org/sid/system-log-daemon) ([busybox-syslogd](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/busybox/), [dsyslog](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dsyslog/), klogd, [inetutils-syslogd](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/i/inetutils/), [sysklogd](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/sysklogd/), [socklog-run](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/socklog/), [syslog-ng](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/syslog-ng/), or [rsyslog](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/rsyslog/)), which push kernel log messages to … wherever the package that you have has been configured to push kernel log messages.  But these don't all capture kernel messages.

Or you can use [systemd](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/s/systemd/), which takes everything that it can get its mitts on — application `syslog()` calls, dæmon output, kernel log buffer — mixes it all together and pushes it to its journal, which you can read with:

```
journalctl -b -x
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute command

```
dmesg
```

And you will get them. If you want to save the message redirect the output to file

```
dmesg >out_file
```

Comment: `dmesg` only prints kernel ring buffer.

Comment: If it's based on Debian the messages will already be saved to `/var/log/kern.log`